# How does a hadoop map operation manage with data redundancy on the HDFS cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Since hadoop runs over HDFS, and data is duplicated across the HDFS cluster for redundancy, does a hadoop map operation actually waste a lot of processor cycles by running mappers over  same data points, on different nodes in the cluster? (as the nodes, by design, have some data overlap between them, as per the replication level).

Or does it first, depending on some job management strategy of some sort, only address part of the nodes, to avoid that kind of duplicate calculation, in some very clever way?

Answer (score 1):

Each mapper gets an individual *InputSplit* to process. So if you have 100 *InputSplits* 100 mappers will be spawned by framework. Then every mapper is going to check if it has all data it needs - if not it will download all required  data and begin the computation. One *InputSplit* will never be assigned twice.